# Focus "jumps" back to earlier component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vuestic

I'm currently developing an application with Vue 3.2.33 and VuesticUI 1.6.4 and I've ran into a problem I can't seem to fix.

I have a form where the user can choose some data, that looks roughly like this

```
<div>
   <select />
</div>
<div>
   <input />
</div>
<div>
   <input />
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is if the user selects something from the `<select>` only by using the keyboard, then after the user have tabbed to the second `<input>` everything is fine.
Though if the user uses the mouse to click on the first input, type something there and then uses tab to get to the next `<input>` the focus jumps back to the `<select>`.

I've tried changing the tabindex, but that didn't seem to fix the issue.

I'm completely lost as to what can cause this kind of behavior.

EDIT:
It only seems to happen when the form is within a modal. If the form is outside a modal everything works as intended.